# Testing if an activity was recreated

Tags: robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I am having trouble testing a method in an activity that is supposed to recreate the activity using robolectric.

The method code is along the lines of:

```
public void onSomeEvent(Event event) {
  // ... do stuff ...
  recreate();
}
```

As long as I comment out the `recreate` at the end there, everything goes fine but if it's not commented out, the test fails saying activity was destroyed. The code seems to work fine in the actual app. 
Also, the event is passed by an `Otto` bus if that is relevant.

**EDIT: Including crash log**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not dispatch event: class com.testapp.event.SomeThingEvent to handler [EventHandler public void com.testapp.activity.MyTestActivity.onSomeThing(com.testapp.event.SomeThingEvent)]: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.throwRuntimeException(Bus.java:458)
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatch(Bus.java:388)
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatchQueuedEvents(Bus.java:369)
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.post(Bus.java:338)
    at com.testapp.activity.MyTestActivityTest.onSomeThing_recreatesActivity(MyTestActivityTest.java:486)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity$ActivityInvoker.with(ShadowActivity.java:637)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.recreate(ShadowActivity.java:558)
    at android.app.Activity.recreate(Activity.java)
    at com.testapp.activity.MyTestActivity.onSomeThing(MyTestActivity.java:253)
    at com.squareup.otto.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:89)
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatch(Bus.java:386)
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatchQueuedEvents(Bus.java:369)
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.post(Bus.java:338)
    at com.testapp.activity.MyTestActivityTest.onSomeThing_recreatesActivity(MyTestActivityTest.java:486)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity$ActivityInvoker.with(ShadowActivity.java:631)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.recreate(ShadowActivity.java:558)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler$ShadowMethodPlan.run(ShadowWrangler.java:507)
    at android.app.Activity.recreate(Activity.java)
    at com.testapp.activity.MyTestActivity.onSomeThing(MyTestActivity.java:253)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.squareup.otto.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:89)
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatch(Bus.java:386)
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatchQueuedEvents(Bus.java:369)
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.post(Bus.java:338)
    at com.testapp.activity.MyTestActivityTest.onSomeThing_recreatesActivity(MyTestActivityTest.java:486)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1387)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:636)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:615)
    at com.testapp.activity.MyTestActivity.onCreate(MyTestActivity.java:83)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity$ActivityInvoker.with(ShadowActivity.java:631)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.recreate(ShadowActivity.java:558)
    at android.app.Activity.recreate(Activity.java)
    at com.testapp.activity.MyTestActivity.onSomeThing(MyTestActivity.java:253)
    at com.squareup.otto.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:89)
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatch(Bus.java:386)
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatchQueuedEvents(Bus.java:369)
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.post(Bus.java:338)
    at com.testapp.activity.MyTestActivityTest.onSomeThing_recreatesActivity(MyTestActivityTest.java:486)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Can you share the failing test error

Comment: @EugenMartynov... added the crash log

Comment: Interesting, I would submit bug on robolectric github page